# Is the usage of plural correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammatical-number, irregular-plurals

Articulate an idea or a concept so that your content **preempts questions**

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's correct. The only plural word here is 'questions' and it's the object of the clause so it doesn't need to agree with the verb. The clause's verb, 'preempts' takes the  singular form with terminal 's' because the subject, 'your content', is singular.